keyframes saves but bones and object just change position without animation
Why when I change the cat's paw position Blender loses the previous one?

Keyframe at 0 made


Keyframe at 40 made


At 0 position lost



cat is here

first problem: you write something, which doesn't fit to your image. So what did u do now? you write: frame 0 -> images shows: frame 1. Please edit your question so that we don't get confused and that it is really crystal clear what you did.

he means that if he comes back to frame 0 the pose that he keyframed for this frame is no longer here

exactly, thank you for this clarification

that's weird, I wonder what's the problem
